# Deleting lines containing a variable

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, text-processing, sed

I have a text file, which contains names. I would like my program to be able to delete names that I tell it to.

First, I have found that I could do it with `sed`, but it just doesn't work for me.

`deletename` is my variable which will contain the pattern that I want to use for the search, and `test.txt` is my text file.

I am using:

```
deletename=0; read deletename; sed...
```

I have tried:

```
sed "/$deletename/ d" test.txt
sed "/$deletename/d" test.txt
sed '/$deletename/ d' test.txt
sed '/$deletename/d' test.txt    
sed -e "/$deletename/ d" test.txt    
sed -e "/$deletename/d" test.txt
sed -e '/$deletename/ d' test.txt
sed -e '/$deletename/d' test.txt
sed -r "/$deletename/ d" test.txt
sed -r "/$deletename/d" test.txt
sed -r '/$deletename/ d' test.txt
sed -r '/$deletename/d' test.txt
```

Since none of this worked, I had an idea, to check the line number that has the pattern, and delete that line. I know I should be using `grep`, but I have absolutely no idea how should I use it.

I have tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
lineno=`expr grep -n $deletename test.txt`
```

Would someone be able to help ? With `sed` or `grep`, doesn't really matter to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `read` to pass the names, and you want to delete lines that contain the names:

```
read deletename; sed "/$deletename/d" test.txt
```

then press <kbd>enter</kbd> and `read` waits for you to enter something, so type whatever you want `deletename` to be, for example `0`, then press <kbd>enter</kbd> again and the `sed` command is executed. The contents of `test.txt` will appear in the terminal, but all the lines that contain `0`, or whatever you typed, will be deleted from the stream (NOT from the file)

If you only want to delete the names themselves it's like this:

```
read deletename; sed "s/$deletename//g" test.txt
```

If you then type `0`, then every instance of `0` will be deleted.

You can redirect (or `tee`) the output to a new file, or **if you want to modify the file in place**, use the `-i` flag (after testing)

```
read deletename; sed -i "/$deletename/d" test.txt
```

In this case you will see no output; the changes will be written to the file instead of displayed in the terminal (on STDOUT).

You need to use double quotes to allow parameter expansion, as single quotes will suppress it. but the most correct way, I think, although not necessary in this simple case, it to use single quotes around the other parts of the expression and quote the variable normally:

```
sed 's/'"$deletename"'//g' test.txt
```

Comment: All I needed was the -i after sed, it works now, thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: @znst great! Sorry I didn't realise what your real issue was immediately :)

Answer (score 3):

Filtering lines is the main role of `grep`. Use `-v` switch to invert match, i.e. only showing lines that does not contain a text. So you can use following command:

```
read deletename; grep -v $deletename test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need, and luckily I alerady figured it out. :)

Comment: It does the same as accepted answer.